Adding two gitpage repositories in Github desktop
I have an existing Git repository synchronised well between RStudio (where my markdown code is), Github Desktop and GitHub (where it, a website, is hosted).
What I'd like to do is add a second repository, and host it as a second website on my account. I read through some advice but am not sure this is entirely possible. I have finished the markdown side of things and can see that the html exports of the future webpages looks as intended. However, when I try to create a new repository on Github Desktop, it seems to link it with the previous one, no matter whether I create a new one, add a branch, etc. So whatever I do, Github Desktop understands any import of this new repository as changes to my previous one and thinks I'm trying to re-write all my previous website pages with entirely new text (which I'm not).
What I did was File-->Add local repository-->[local path]-->Add
Despie that my new site has it's _site.yml file correct and is in a separate project folder, etc., Github Desktop reads it as a copy of the previous website I created.
I'm not even sure where to start from and where the problem is. Could you give me some initial points of search?
